Conceptual doubts about Chladni Plates
For a divulgative project that I'm working on, we've built a two Chladni Plates a square and a circular one. The idea is to do a demonstration in front of high schoolers, accompanied by an explanation of the phenomenon. I've been reading about the topic to understand it as much as I can but I still have some questions that I rather have resolved.
The idea of a standing wave on a rope seems pretty straightforward to me. You have a rope, let's say, fixed on both ends, and when a wave propagates through it, it will bounce back. And if the frequency is the right one (resonant frequencies), there will be fixed points at which the two waves completely cancel out (nodes).
When it comes to translating this into the 2D case, there's some things that I don't fully understand.
First of all, whichever is the equation that defines the ressonant frequencies of a plate, I know that it has to have some dependencies on two modal numbers, $$ and $$, from the book "The Physics of Musical Instruments, Fletcher & Rossing, (1998)" I've taken the following equation: $f_{mn}=\frac{v}{2L} \sqrt{m^2+n^2}$ . Which suggests that a single frequency can lead to multiple patterns. What I wonder is what will determine the specific pattern given a certain frequency. In our setup, everything is pretty symmetrical, the plate is connected to the speaker by a single point on its center, we've seen other setups in which the plate is connected by four points, and I also wonder how that would affect the patterns. But either way, I hardly see any of this setups producing a pattern in which $m \neq n$, can this happen, and where would this asymmetries come from? I've also seen the classical version of the experiment done with a violin bow played along the side of the plate, intuitively I would think this case is less symmetrical but the patterns generated still seem to be pretty symmetrical, what's going on there?
If in the rope the standing wave was originated by the wave canceling itself, I want to imagine the same thing happening here. I can do so if I imagine our circular setup with waves propagating from the center and coming back once they hit the edge. I even could do the same with the square one if we somehow had a setup that allowed to generate a plane wave across each axis, but if I imagine the waves from the speaker propagating from the center in a circular way and then bouncing of the plane sides of the square to meet the new circular waves that are being generated, I would only expect chaos to come from this, and I don't know if this is the right picture of what is going on. Also, in the case of the circular plate, although the cases in which we only have circular nodes seem pretty easy to understand, I find it harder to think about the patterns having an angular component, mainly because I know that the waves can't travel around in circles.
Furthermore, I know that all of this only describes a plate with clamped edges, which is not at all the case of the Chladni Plate since it has free edges, which i assume to be a much harder problem.
I appreciate any help, thanks a lot.

"Whence the asymmetry?" The normal modes of a system with some symmetry don't have to display that symmetry.  Take the simple case of a rectangular plate with fixed boundary (which corresponds to the $f_{mn}$ in your post). The normal modes are products of sines, and the wavelengths along each direction can vary independently, so the normal modes don't have to by symmetric under 90-deg rotations.  The patterns are complicated, there is likely degeneracy (imodes with the same $f$), and thus how the modes are excited matters. Can you clarify your question? I'm not exactly sure it really is.

Yeah sorry, I understand that there can be degeneracy, but I would like to know in a bit more detail what are the ways in which the modes can be exited to generate different patterns, given a certain frequency. Let's say you make vibrate with the same frequency a plate, first with a speaker attached only to it's center, then with the speaker attached to 4 equally spaced points along the plate and finally with a violin bow along the side. Would these lead to different patterns? Is this what you mean by the way the modes can be excited?

They would lead to different patterns, yes.  The fact that there is degeneracy means that any linear combination of normal (i.e., resonant) modes with the same frequency is also a normal mode, and can hence be excited.  These modes, while having the same frequency, will have different nodal and anti-nodal patterns, and hence depending on how you excite it, you'll get one of these linear combinations.  For instance, using a bow at some point on the plate likely creates and anti-node at that part of the plate, which determines which linear combination is excited.
